# {.NET} Streaming MP4 file through HttpListener sends entire file instead of part that's being currently watched

Tags: vb.net, networking, video-streaming, mp4, httplistener

*Well,i have to ask on a forum like a true normie for this once again after long time..*

This is the code for preparing response..

```
mycontext = myserver.GetContext()
mycontext.Response.ContentType = "video/mp4"
mycontext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=fileboi.mp4")
mycontext.Response.SendChunked = True
inputstream.Position = 0
Dim lngBytesProcessed As Long
lngBytesProcessed=0
While lngBytesProcessed < inputstream.Length
    intBytesInCurrentBlock = inputstream.Read(bytBuffer, 0, Math.Min(blocksize, lngFileLength - lngBytesProcessed))
    mycontext.Response.OutputStream.Write(bytBuffer, 0, intBytesInCurrentBlock)
    mycontext.Response.OutputStream.Flush()
    lngBytesProcessed = lngBytesProcessed + CLng(intBytesInCurrentBlock)
    RefreshEv(lngBytesProcessed, lngFileLength)
End While
```

Also, when playing the stream in vlc, it just loads the entire file and doesn't even play it.

Comment: Usually you’d need to implement ranges support in HTTP for it to be possible to stream without downloading the entire file

Comment: I tried adding _Accept-Ranges: bytes_ to the headers, and it resulted in _The specified network name is no longer available_ error in case of streaming through VLC and through Firefox it still streams the entire file.